# iOS 10: Got a keyboard will show notification but keyboard was not on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I have a function to handle the `UIKeyboardWillShow` notification. What happens though is that when I segue out of that specific view controller to another one and then come back, if the keyboard was still on screen before it again calls the function even though it's not on screen anymore and shows this in the console: "got a keyboard will show notification but keyboard was not on screen." However, if I hide the keyboard while still in the initial view controller and then segue and come back, the function isn't called as expected. I've tried `resignFirstResponder()` in `viewWillDisappear()` but it still happens. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling `resignFirstResponder()`?

Comment: @between_compiles I'm just calling it straight in the `viewWillDisappear()` as such: `resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: Have you tried calling it on the particular text field that is triggering the keyboard? such as `mytextField.resignFirstResponder()`

Comment: Just tried, no luck. :/

Comment: I assume you are adding an observer for the `UIKeyboardWillShow` notification when the `viewWillAppear(_:)`. Are you removing the observer at any point?

Comment: I have `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)` in `viewDidLoad()` and then I have `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` in `deinit`

Comment: Ok I switched the adding of the observer to `viewWillAppear(_:)` and the removing of the observer to `viewWillDisappear(_:)` and now it works. Thanks for your help! Don't know why I didn't do that to begin with...